# SharePoint 2013 Create Unique Survey Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have set item permission on Sharepoint surveys where users are able to read only their own responses, however in addition I need to create a permission level to give some other users possibility to read all available responses.

Currently I have the setting shown below in the image, and I need to stick with that but create some permission level to give read access to specified users.

Could you please help achieve that. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a SharePoint Group with the users who require access to all items
2. Grant that group  "Manage Hierarchy" permission on your survey.

Note: this will also grant users the ability to edit items as well. If that is an issue then you can created a custom permission level based on above mentioned permission levels and uncheck the edit items option.

Comment: Thanks for response, the thing is that we are managing group in a custom user management system we developed so this is not an option. I have created a custom level permission and assigned it to a group, but the problem is that when I disable edit option from the permission level users are not able to responses, although see surveys.

Comment: Manage Hierarchy permisssion level without the edit item option seems to work fine for me i.e. just disallows edits on the item but stll able to view all the items.

Comment: I can't find the Manage Hierarchy option, could you please navigate where you see it? Can this option be missing in foundation version of sharepoint?

Comment: Go to top level site settings ->site permissions ->from the ribbon select permission levels to see all the permission levels in the site collection.

Comment: Yeah I did that but the Manage Hierarchy is missing in the list... Anyway as the full access for the particular users was not an issue I used you suggestion creating a group for them and granted a custom permission. So issue is solved. Thanks a lot! :)